# Angular - Variables being reset after ngAfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an issue where after I (successfully) use variables in ngAfterViewInit(), they all reset.

I have a couple of @Viewchild and normal variables, that are being used or set in ngAfterViewInit, however when a couple of events that I added after the init are called, these very same variables are shown only as `undefined`

Code (slightly simplified):

```
// Variable declaration
@ViewChild('imagearea') imageArea: ElementRef;

dragBottomRight: HTMLElement;


ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dragBottomRight = this.imageArea.nativeElement.querySelector('.br');

    this.imageArea.nativeElement.addEventListener("mousedown", this.dragStart);

    // This correctly logs the elements
    console.log(this.imageArea, this.dragBottomRight);
}

dragStart(e: MouseEvent) {
    // This logs: undefined, undefined
    console.log(this.imageArea, this.dragBottomRight);
}
```

I've tried setting the variables to static, and a pretty much identical code structure seems to work for my coworker.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you attaching the `dragStart` event listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is happen, because you are not binding the function to the same context.

you need to change:

`this.imageArea.nativeElement.addEventListener("mousedown", this.dragStart.bind(this));`

to keep the same context for the function, or just use arrow functions.

Comment: I had another function that looked like `e => this.myFunction(e)`, that helped me solve it.
Thanks for explaining it further!

Answer (score 0):

Your Eventlistener is bounded using the wrong context, use `bind` to bind the right context or preferably use angular renderer to add your eventlistener:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dragBottomRight = this.imageArea.nativeElement.querySelector('.br');
    this.dragStartListener = this.renderer.listen(this.dragBottomRight, 'mousedown', event => this.dragStart(event));
}
```

To unbind the listener just call `this.dragStartListener`.

Note: You should use angular event bindings to bind you listeners, unless there's no other way (e.g. dynamically created elements).